# Summing Multiple Records by maxdate

Tags: t-sql, sum, maxdate

I have a table with the following data

```
Bldg        Suit    SQFT     Date
1           1       1,000    9/24/2012              
1           1       1,500    12/31/2011
1           2       800      8/31/2012
1           2       500      10/1/2005
```

I want to write a query that will sum the max date for each suit record, so the desired result would be 1,800, and must be in one cell/row.  This will ultimately be part of subquery, I am just not getting what I expect with the queries I have writtren so far.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a950/17)):

```
select sum(t1.sqft) Total
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select max(dt) mxdt, suit, bldg
  from yourtable
  group by suit, bldg
) t2
  on t1.dt = t2.mxdt
  and t1.bldg = t2.bldg
  and t1.suit = t2.suit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
; With Data As
(
    Select Bldg, Suit, SQFT, Row_Number() Over (Partition By Bldg, Suit Order By Date DESC) As RowID
    From   YourTableNameHere
)
Select Bldg, Sum(SQFT) As TotalSQFT
From   Data
Where  RowId = 1
Group By Bldg
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, I am using T SQL.  I am trying to work with both of these, so far, no luck.  I will keep at it, thanks for your help!